# FileSaver.js Chrome Issue, Multiple documents

Tags: javascript, ajax, filesaver.js

I'm using Chrome v67 and FileSaver.js.

This code works in FF & Edge but not in Chrome.

```
var ajaxSettings = {
    url: "my/api/method",
    data: JSON.stringify(myItems),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            var dateToAppend = moment().format("YYYYMMDD-HHmmss");
            createPdf("pdfDoc_" + dateToAppend + ".pdf", data[0]);
            saveFile("txtDoc_" + dateToAppend + ".txt", data[1]);

            //sleep(2000).then(() => {
            //    saveFile("txtDoc_" + dateToAppend + ".txt", data[1]);
            //});
        }
    }
}

//function sleep(time) {
    //return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
//}

function createPdf(filename, pdfBytes) {
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") > -1) {
        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + encodeURIComponent(pdfBytes));
    }
    else {
        saveFile(fileName, data);
    }
}

function saveFile(fileName, data) {
    var decodedByte64 = atob(data);
    var byteVals = new Array(decodedByte64.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < decodedByte64.length; i++) {
        byteVals[i] = decodedByte64.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byte8bitArray = new Uint8Array(byteVals);

    var blob = new Blob([byte8bitArray]);
    saveAs(blob, fileName); //FileSaver.js
}
```

The result of calling the API is an array with 2 byte arrays in it.
The byte arrays are the documents.

If I run this code, as a user would, then what happens is that the first document gets "downloaded" but the second does not.  Attempting to do this a second time without refreshing the page results in no documents being "downloaded".  The "download" word is in quotes because it already has been downloaded, what I'm really trying to do is generate the documents from the byte arrays.

This is the strange bit ... if I open the console and place a breakpoint on the "saveFile" call and immediately hit continue when the debugger lands on the breakpoint then all is well with the world and the 2 documents get downloaded.

I initially thought it was a timing issue so I put a 2 second delay on this to see if that was it but it wasn't.  The only thing I've managed to get working is the breakpoint which I'm obviously not going to be able to convince the users to start doing no matter how much I want them to.

Any help or pointers are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably faced a message at the top left corner of your browser stating

> https://yoursite.com wants to
>   Download multiple files
>   [Block] [Allow]

If you don't have it anymore, it's probably because you clicked on "Block".
You can manage this restriction in `chrome://settings/content/automaticDownloads`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) but unfortunately I don't have anything in either of those lists (the allow or block) - this works when I do the breakpoint thing (see above)

Comment: You can click on padlock on url address bar and on "Site settings", then you can manage all options for the website, including automatic downloads.

Comment: Hi Matteo, I don't that's an issue either unfortunately.  Like I said, this works if I debug it but not when it runs normally

Comment: @Boomer yes it works when you add a break point because then it is not considered as multiple simultaneous downloads. Check again this settings page, and see if you have your domain listed there. If so click the "..." button then remove the restriction.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, the problem has not been resolved at this time.  As for the settings page, the setting: "Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file" is switched on.  Both the "Block" & "Allow" lists are empty.